# Is there the best data structure to only insert and search for particular words in the text file line by line?

Tags: data-structures

I am struggling with my homework, I have to design data structure/s suitable for the specific scenario. I have a text to load line by line. After that i have to:

1. Print line numbers on which a given word exists.
2. Print the total number of times a given word occurs (on a specific line)
3. Print whole line of words.

I must not use programming language, it must be only description of this problem.

I was thinking about linked list of arrays, where one Node is a line that contains array of words. I do not need much space for that but in the worst case searching operation will be O(n*n). 
I also have tries in my mind, however number of either lines or words in particular line is not defined but set to be max 4 bytes integer thus it can use a lot of space.

Comment: Hint: Consider using a dictionary or hash map. The key is a word, and the value is a list of [line, count] pairs. And of course you'd need an array of lines so that you can satisfy #2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so if word is repeated i just add it to existing hash?

Comment: If the word is new, you add it to to the hash map. If a word is repeated, you increment the count for the existing entry in the hash map.